# Is it possible to compute a correlation between two variables from just means, standard deviations and sample sizes?

Tags: correlation, standard-deviation, mean, descriptive-statistics

Is it possible to compute the correlation between two variables with just the mean, standard deviation, and sample size?

If so, how would I go about it?

Comment: No; you need the covariance too. Look at the definition to see that. Alternatively, think about it graphically. Draw $x$ and $y$ axes. I am now going to tell you the mean and SD of each variable and the number of data points. Now tell me the relationship between $x$ and $y$ variables. You can't do it.  There is no information on the relationship in the marginal summaries.

Comment: Or even simpler, perhaps, have 2 columns of data with numbers in order from 1 to 100 in each. They will have a perfect correlation of +1. Now flip the order of one of the columns, and repeat. Correlation is no longer +1, even though the means and SDs of the individual columns are unchanged.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible to compute correlation with just information about the individual variables.

The correlation is a particular measure of how they vary "together". Information like mean and standard deviation is how they each behave on their own, without any consideration of other variables.

(Specifically, correlation is a property of their *joint* distribution, while the quantities you mention are properties of the *marginal* distribution, and will be consistent with different joint distributions.)

In the diagram below, the populations y and z were drawn from have the same mean and standard deviation:

[image]

Yet as you see, their correlations with x are quite different.

If I only told you the means and standard deviations and n's, you would have no way to distinguish whether I meant the first plot or the second plot (or indeed, any number of other possible plots).

A simple analogy is to think of a two dimensional table, with totals at the bottom and the right edge. If you only look at the row and columns totals, you can't figure out much about which cells in the interior of the table contributed the values. So these margins:

```
                    Total
        ?   ?    ?   10
        ?   ?    ?   20
        ?   ?    ?   15
 Total 10  20   15
```

are consistent with all of these tables:

```
 10   0    0         2   5   3          0   5   5
  0  20    0         5   8   7          5   5  10
  0   0   15         3   7   5          5  10   0
```

Comment: Outstanding explanation, Glen!